# Preparing Position Time Graph and Velocity Time Graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

So, I'm a little confused on how this would actually work.

For a Homework question, I needed to analyze a short little simulation where I collect Data to prepare a velocity-time plot and position-time plot. I'm a little confused about how what I do. For the velocity-time plot part

The Data I collected was:

Seconds (s)    --- Fall (m)

- 0 --- 0
- 1 --- 4.9
- 2 --- 19.4
- 3 --- 44.1
- 4 --- 79.2
- 5 --- 123
- 6 --- 176
- 7 --- 240

Comment: Where do you face the problem plot y coordinate on y axis and time on spx axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the position- time plot: x axes t in s, y axes s in m
for the velocity calculate it for every time interval, since this is just 1s you have the mean velocity as for example:  s5-s4/1s =0.44m/s which you plot at t=4.5s